# How do I Maximize the mitzva of "guarding the matzos"?

Tags: matzah

This mitzva is to guard the grain for the matzos to ensure no moisture has gotten to it between harvesting and baking.

Is there a date from which I can earn mitvas by guarding grain or can I harvest at any time.

Does a guarded piece of grain need to actually turned into matza and used on Pesach in order to realize the mitzva or may I guard the same piece indefinitely?

Does increasing the amount I guard increase the reward or does it max out at a kezait?

Are women obligated in this mitzva?

Comment: `This mitzva is to guard the grain for the matzos to ensure no moisture has gotten to it between harvesting and baking.` 1) Not clear that Exod. 12:17 implies a mitzva as opposed to a necessary condition for the validity of the matzos mitzva (though there are sources indicating מצוה בו יותר מבשלוחו applies, this doesn't imply preparation is an independent mitzva). 2) Sources differ as to the reason for the sh'mira (whether to prevent leavening or to ensure the matzos are made with intent that they be for the mitzva). 3) Different opinions about the part of the process to which sh'mira applies.

Comment: From the Minchas Chinuch 10:2 it seems that it isn’t a stand alone Mitzvah by itself, rather it’s part of the mitzvah of eating matza, to have that matza that your eating, to have been watched.